# Change Style Child div when parent div active in accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use as accordion in any pages.
I want to change opacity Child div (**LogoAccordion**) when accordion active is parent div.
My html code is:

```
<div id="Accordion">
    <div id="PnlAccordion">
                        <div id="LogoAccordion">

                        </div>
                        <div id="ContentAccordion">

                        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PnlAccordion">
                        <div id="LogoAccordion">

                        </div>
                        <div id="ContentAccordion">

                        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code is:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
                activePanel = $("#Accordion #PnlAccordion:first");
                $(activePanel).addClass('active');

                //Add By Opacity Full
                activePanelLogo = $("#Accordion #PnlAccordion #LogoAccordion:first");
                $(activePanelLogo).css('opacity','0.9');
                //LogoAccordion

                $("#Accordion").delegate('#PnlAccordion', 'click', function(e){
                     if( ! $(this).is('.active') ){
                        $(activePanel).animate({width: "25px"}, 300);
                        $(this).animate({width: "845px"}, 300);
                        $('#Accordion #PnlAccordion').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                        activePanel = this;
                     };
                });
```

But my code only works for the first page load.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `.parent` and `.parents`

```
on("click", function() {
```

previous element if it's a div or emtpy list:

```
$(this).parent("div")
```

traverses hierachy backwards until it finds the #accordion

```
$(this).parents("#accordion");
```

If i understand the question right, you want something like:

```
$(this).parents("#accordion>div.active")
```

Comment: i want when first div (#PnlAccordion) actived child this div (#LogoAccordion) change opacity style.